# Why is GuzzleHttp trying to use port 80 for https?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to use `GuzzleHttp` in a Laravel 5.3 application to connect to `https://api.example.com` (note the `https`).

```
<?php

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.example.com/accounts', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => "Token $token"
    ]
]);

var_dump($res->getBody());
```

However, I am getting an error that it can't connect on port 80(!) despite the `https` in the url. Even when I specify port 443 (e.g. `https://api.example.com:443/accounts`) it still gives me this error about port 80:

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.example.com port 80:
Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Why won't it connect on port 443? Why is it attempting to connect on port 80?

Comment: have you checked the api is not redirecting?

Comment: @nogad Well, what do ya know? I checked the output through a raw `curl` request and it came back with 301 (moved permanently). Interesting. Will investigate more later.

Comment: funny what happens when you check ;-)

Comment: @nogad I guess I just assumed a secure api would never redirect https to http, only the other way around. Guess I was wrong. Turns out you have to put a slash at the end of the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here. I looked into this more and discovered that I was getting a `301 Moved Permanently` / `Location: http://api.example.com/accounts` when requesting `https://api.example.com/accounts`

I was baffled as to why I would be redirected from `https` to `http` but discovered the issue is with the api. Turns out you *have to* add a slash at the end. `https://api.example.com/accounts/` does not redirect to port 80 but works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the $ for the token variable (and the double quotes)?

Perhaps you meant `'Authorization' => "Token {$token}"` Maybe it's redirecting because of wrong auth headers

Comment: That's just a placeholder for an actual token I don't want to reveal. In my code I have `'Authorization' => 'Token ' . $token`